# who add L,geoJson and L.icon in one variable and show/hide with L.control.layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My English is not the best but I will try to describe the problem.

well i try to add two types of functions of leaflet in only one variable and show/hide all this controlled with L.control.layers, the problem her is the L.control. layer only show me L.geoJson or L.icon but not both

```
var rutavistaimss = L.geoJson(rutavs,{color:'red'}); 
var ruta18D = L.geoJson(ruta18d,{color:'green'}); 
var rutaperife = L.geoJson(rutaperi,{color:'blue'}); 
var rutamirasi = L.geoJson(rutamira,{color:'#2cd176'}); 
var ruta8ampli = L.geoJson(ruta8AmpMo,{color:'#6d418b'});

var mki=L.icon.mapkey({icon:"bus",color:'#725139',background:'#f2c357',size:30}); 
var paradasrutavs= L.marker([25.41437583170945,-100.9632524322901],{icon:mki});

var rutatodoeuno = paradasrutavs,rutavistaimss;

var capaderutas = { "ruta vista imss": rutatodoenuno, 
"ruta 18 directa": ruta18D , 
"ruta periferico": rutaperife, 
"ruta mira sierra": rutamirasi, 
"ruta 8 ampliacion morelos": ruta8ampli };

L.control.layers(null,capaderutas,{collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
var rutatodoeuno = paradasrutavs,rutavistaimss;
```

isn't doing anything useful for you. Try adding the two layers you want to combine into a `L.layerGroup` which will behave like a single layer as far as `L.control.layers` is concerned.

```
var rutatodoeuno = L.layerGroup([paradasrutavs,rutavistaimss]);
```